# is it possible to index a iframe

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

We have created an web application that gives the client the possibility to use his websites as an online showroom (cars, bikes, etc etc).

What is offered is photo's, information about the vehicles and so on.

However, we would like to offer this as an iframe rather then developing plugins for certain CMS systems (Drupal, WordPress etc etc) or giving an file_get_contents/curl method.

The only downside we can think of is that the content within the iframe isn't going to be indexed by Google.

Is it possible to let it be indexed to the parent webpage? So that the content of the iframe belongs to Domain A.

We've tried it with canonical tags but this didn't work.

Any ideas or is this just not possible?.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither about programming nor about Google Analytics.

Comment: why is this question off-topic?

Comment: You seem to ask how Google (the search engine) indexes content, and that not a problem that would be solved in code. It might be that I misunderstood your question (and in any case this is just my opinion and not necessarily correct) but as it stands I think this is a question about the inner working of Google and would be better discussed on the webmasters SE site.